# Relation of probability of a random variable with its standard deviation and mean?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I just came across this question:

What is the probability that the value of a normal random variable X exceeds its mean by more than 1.9 times its standard deviation?

I'm not really sure how to approach this to be honest. Is there any equation I need to know that related all of them?

Comment: The advantage of working in "standard deviation units" is precisely that you can answer questions like this just by using the standard normal (mean $0$, $\sigma =1 $).   Thus the answer is the same as the probability that a standard normal variable exceeds $1.9$ so $0.02871656$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to calculate the following probability

$$\mathbb{P}[X>\mu+1.9\sigma]$$

now standardize and find

$$\mathbb{P}\left[Z>\frac{\mu+1.9\sigma-\mu}{\sigma}\right]=\mathbb{P}[Z>1.9]=1-\Phi(1.9)\approx0.029$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I got it! It took me a while to get what values I needed to use for standardization but this really cleared it up!